# Java Get And Set Methods

Tags: java, function, get, set

I'm new to Java and i want to know what is the purpose of Get and Set functions, and i want to know where it is being used. Please answer clearly because i'm still new to java field.
Thank you a lot for answering my simple question.

Comment: A get method returns a value. A set method changes the internal state of the object it is being called on (i.e. changing the value of an integer).

Comment: They are simple conventions designed to make it easier to tell when you get a value from a method or set a value to a method